# Weird output after changing the variable

Tags: c

I am using DevC++ as my compiler on Windows XP. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
  int a;
  printf("%d\n", a);
  int b = a;
  a = 10;
  printf("%d %d %d", a, b, a);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
2
10 2 10
```

I don't understand why the variable `a` gets the value `2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int a;
printf("%d\n", a);
```

A uninitialized object has an indeterminate value. Accessing an uninitialized object is undefined behavior. If you try to print its value, you can get `2` printed, or `42` or your application can crash.

Comment: Ok does that mean? an uninitialised variable, wont throw an Error, but would automatically set some junk value in C??

Comment: It means anything can happen but most likely some junk being printed.

Comment: Thats weired then.. because with python the same concept gives NameError, and Java takes a default as 0. Thanks.. I thought, There was some problem with the compiler :)

Comment: @ouah You said it must be either 2 or 42 or program crash... But for my case it is 35 Why?

Comment: @NarayanKandel those were just examples. It can contain any number. That's what [indeterminate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indeterminate) means.

Comment: @ouah Why do you write in the answer `you can get 2 printed, or 42 or your application can crash.`

Comment: @NarayanKandel: those are three things which can happen if you read the value of an uninitialized object. No-one said they were the *only* things that can happen.

Comment: @Whiskey: C++ doesn't hold your hand in that way :) Your program is compiled into machine code, and when you run it, that machine code is given straight to the CPU, which of course is a physical device made of silicon. In Python and Java, your program is compiled into an intermediate code which is given to a virtual machine. Virtual machines offer more predictable behaviour than physical machines, but they are slower (usually this doesn't really matter).

Comment: @Oktalist Awesome Explanation.. now it get it... wish could have made few more +1 for explaining. anyways.. while True: print "Thanks";

Answer (score 0):

Variable `a` is not initialized by you so it has some random value. In another application run / after computer restart it might be equal to another value. You have to assign some value in order to be sure that `a` is equal to it.

Comment: Not "it will", it *may* be equal to another value. Undefined behavior doesn't have to be inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

It must be `garbage value` store at the address compiler assign for variable `a`, because it isn't initialize.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Undefined Behavior.

I got 4334 in my computer with the same compiler.